# Export to text file from Access missing carriage return at the end of the line

Tags: vb.net

I have a database in Access and I need to export that information into a text file The problem that I have is that it is not exported in the correct format. This is an example of the text file that is been exported:

```
info|info1|info3|info4|info5|info6|info7|info8|  <this is the wrong format
info|info1|info3|info4|info5|info6|info7|info8   <this is the correct format
```

As you can see, my code is inserting a vertical line at the end of the row instead of a carriage return.

Please see my code and any help will be great:

```
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
    connetionString = "connection string.accdb;"
    cnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)

    Dim dtResult As New DataTable
    cnn.Open()
    'Change the query
    Dim dataAdap As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", cnn)
    dataAdap.Fill(dtResult)
    cnn.Close()

    'Change the path to your desired path
    Dim RUTA As String = "path were i want to put the text file\"
    Dim ARCHIVOTXT As String = "filename of the text file.txt"

    If Not Directory.Exists(RUTA) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(RUTA)
    End If

    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(RUTA + ARCHIVOTXT)
    Try
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each row As DataRow In dtResult.Rows
            sb = New StringBuilder
            For Each col As DataColumn In dtResult.Columns
                sb.Append(row(col.ColumnName) & "|")
            Next
            writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        If Not writer Is Nothing Then writer.Close()
    End Try
    MsgBox("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: `Yourstring.Remove(Yourstring.Length - 1)` just a quick way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
For Each col As DataColumn In dtResult.Columns
        sb.Append(row(col.ColumnName) & "|")
Next
writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
```

You could just use:  `writer.WriteLine(String.Join("|", row.ItemArray))`

`String.Join("|", row.ItemArray)` concatenates the `ToString()` result of each value held by the row separating the values with a "|".

Comment: What about the last item, won't it have the pipe as well?

Comment: than you TnTinMn it´s exactly what i was looking for you have save mmy life :-)